# Confusion about the "Scoped objects" and "Transient objects"

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to understand the meaning of "Scoped objects" and "Transient objects". I was asked in the interview about the usage of this and I said :

> Transient objects are always different; a new instance is provided to
> every controller and every service.

Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests. I gave an example If I have a dashboard with 3-4 widgets and each of these 4 widgets is calling an action method of `DashboardController` by injecting `IDashboardService` in the controller. If the `IDashboardService` is registered as Scoped then only 1 instance is going to be created for "**Action1 Widget**" which will be used in another subsequent request in "**Action2 Widget**", "**Action3 Widget**" and "**Action 4 Widget**" without creating a new instance.

Now I am not sure if the above sentence is right or wrong but the interviewer asked me how does the `.Net core framework` know it has to use the same instance as the HTTP request
is stateless.

So can anyone please explain how this works and how the browser and server know if its the same session and how the browser informs to the .net framework that its the same
session so use the same instance in case of `Scoped` and new for `Transient`?

Comment: I think there's some confusion between you and the interviewer. The interviewer is assuming each widget is making a new HTTP request (e.g. AJAX, hence, a new object) and, as I understand it, _you're_ building the widgets server-side on page load all 4 in the same request. Also, a "session" has nothing to do with it either way. We're talking per HTTP request here, not per session.

Comment: Session is not a request

Comment: It was a trick question. Statelessness has to do with each request being separate and not maintaining state between them. Within the request, though, it's building the dependency graph in that context, so it doesn't need to know about other requests. Statelessness would only be a problem if it needed to return the same instance across multiple requests in the same session, for example.

Comment: @RobIII thanks for clarification but how does the .net core framework knows  if its the same web request or a different one? I am not clear with the usage of "Scope" service. I will really appreciate If you can please give me an example to illustrate how the framework keeps track of Scope instance for HTTP request?

Comment: It isn't .net core...it is asp.net core which is an important distinction. Internally, asp.net core creates an HttpContext that represents the request and the lifetime of that request and is bound together with clever caching and async local. It absolutely DOES create a state for the duration of the request, which is what allows it to patch into the dependency graph and determine all of the requests that are necessary for resolution and reuse them as need be.

Comment: @madreflection ok so in 1 action method if there is a multiple use of IDashboardService  then framework will create only single instance of IDashboardService  registered as scope but only within a single action method and not a difference action method call?

Comment: _"how does the .net core framework knows if its the same web request or a different one"_ You should really look into what a request is (a single http-request that is) and what a session means. You can't expect us to explain all that in a SO answer or comment. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidL Can you give me any example when we should be using Scoped Service and why?

Comment: There are plenty of questions on stack overflow for when to use a specific lifestyle, but in a few words, you should always prefer a scoped lifestyle whenever you do not have a singleton, or when you do not need new instances per injection. In an application with natural scoping (like an http request), the majority of your dependencies should be registered as scoped where possible, especially if they have semantic meaning that is tied to that request. Cross-functional concerns like logging ids or authentication are useful as scoped services.

Comment: Your example of "widgets" is not precise enough. If I were the interviewer, I would want to know what a widget was and how you were populating its information. Were these API calls that populated the control, or were they emitted in the Razor view? The former involves 4 additional requests, each with its own scope. The latter is all within a single scope. If you can't communicate that difference, how does the interviewer know that you understand what scoped lifestyle is?

Comment: I know that interviewing is not easy, but having recently interviewed 5 straight candidates who could not speak precisely enough to communicate how well they understood what they knew (or thought they knew) or how the technology worked, I strongly advise you to unpack technical details as much as possible and not rely on colloquial descriptions. If they're asking you a technical question, they expect the details.

Comment: @madreflection if its a 4 different api calls then IDashboardService will be a new instance each time even though IDashboardService is registered as Scoped service?

Comment: Yes, because each API call is a new request! Each request is a separate scope. As David L said, thre are plenty of questions on SO about this. Read up.

Comment: @madreflection I saw a video of Scope service where the author implemented an action method and injected a service which serves a new GUID and display in the browser. Now when the author refreshes the same tab in the browser it always show the same GUID value but when the author refreshes the page in a new tab of same browser it shows a new GUID value. This service is registered as scope. So how does it works in the same tab of same browser that GUID returns the same value?

Comment: Caching? Maybe each tab is cached separately. Probably didn't do Ctrl+F5 (force reload). No way to know be sure without more information.

Comment: As a rule, I don't give credence to YouTube videos. They tend to be low quality at best, and they seem to be an endless source of misunderstandings and bad questions on StackOverflow. This may very well be a prime example of that.

Comment: @madreflection I saw a video at Pluralright. Is there any good open source project to follow to learn this and better understand this? if you are aware of any

Comment: I just ran the same test you described, and each refresh in the same tab (no forced refreshes, just F5) yields a new GUID for each request. I also injected it in both the constructor and the action method (using `[FromServices]` on the parameter) and both yielded the same instance of the service (as identified by the GUID generated in the service implementation's constructor), so it's *definitely* registered as scoped. Whatever you saw in that video was configured incorrectly. *(mic drop)*

Comment: In a nutshell the web server manages the lifetime of the service scope per request. Simplified; `HttpContext.RequestServices = IServiceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;`